# Is it possible to display contents on dynamic island while app is in foreground?

Tags: ios, dynamic-island

I have followed Apple's document and create an example, the content i want to show only appear when app enter background. I wonder is it possible to display while in foreground?Thanks every much.

Comment: Did you find an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to display content in your app which is displayed in the area where the dynamic island resides. This content will be hidden if another background app uses the dynamic island. But if no other app uses the dynamic island, your replacement layouts are going to display just fine.